# Expression Engine removing server from href

Tags: expressionengine

I just found out that if I create an html link within an entry that has my home server in it (ex. http://www.lcbcchurch.com/img/etc), it .removes my server (ex. /img/etc.)... Is there an option somewhere that I can turn this “feature” off. I do not want it to take off the server portion of the link. I use the site information in an iphone app via json request and it is currently messing up my links. Thoughts?

Comment: What kind of field is this happening with? Is the text of the link (contents of the `<a>` tag) being truncated, or just the value of the `href`? Is it changed in the database (i.e. if you edit the entry in EE, is the value changed), or is it only on the front-end? Your question is not very detailed, please improve!

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail. The text is not being truncated, just the value of the href. It is being changed in the database as well, not just on the front end.

Comment: Hmm ... and is this just a plain EE text field? Or text input? Is there any formatting set for the field on the back-end? (See Admin --> Channel Administration --> Channel Fields, then click on your field group's name).

Comment: So...just to be clear, you're saying that: A) You link to "http://www.lcbcchurch.com/img/etc" in an EE entry, B) you then save the entry in EE's control panel, and C) The DB table row for this entry and the generated template code *both* show an altered version of the URL (i.e. "http://www.lcbcchurch.com") instead of the actual URL?

Comment: As mentioned above - need to know the field type, is it a wysiwyg type field?

Comment: Sorry, it's actually a tiny MCE description field. I'm using the tiny plugin for EE. So I guess this is probably a tiny MCE problem, not EE. Does anyone else use any sort of wysiwyg field that isn't buggy? Let me know, thanks!

Comment: Got everything figured out, thanks for the attempted help. Sorry for bothering you guys.